# Extracting the repeating values from a range of cells

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2007

I need help with this situation. I have values in cells A1:F1 (1,1,1,2,2,4) and in G1 I would like only repeating values to be extraced which in this case would be (12). More examples: (2,2,3,3,4,4) would be (234). 
(0,0,1,2,3,9) would be (0). and if there is no repeating values in the cells, then it should be blank.

```
 Sample Data            Expected Result
1   2   3   4   4   4       4
0   1   1   1   2   4       1
1   1   2   2   3   5       12
0   2   2   3   5   5       25
0   1   2   3   4   5       
0   2   3   3   4   4       34
0   0   2   3   3   4       03
0   1   1   2   3   3       13
0   0   0   1   4   4       04
0   2   3   3   4   5       3
0   1   1   2   3   3       13
1   1   2   3   3   4       13
0   1   2   3   3   5       3
0   1   2   3   3   3       3
0   1   1   2   3   4       1
0   1   1   2   4   4       14
0   1   2   3   4   4       4
1   1   2   4   4   5       14
0   0   0   2   2   2       02
0   0   0   1   2   3       0
```

Comment: You should also include examples of data that returns the incorrect result, along with the actual and expected results.

Comment: I tried to enter a picture for a sample but there is a problem on the site now i guess. and I can't enter data because it gets mixed up all.

Comment: @pnuts, I deleted that formula because it's wrong. sorry.

Comment: Max, **much** better to have the sample and NOT the screenshot.  It is very hard to copy a screenshot into an excel worksheet, unless you have some method I don't have here.

Comment: yes, I did it now. thanks.

Comment: In order to prevent the website from messing up your table format, you can (as I did when editing), select the data and then use the "code sample" option.

Comment: Thanks, I figured it out after a couple of trials :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy to do with a User Defined Function (UDF)

This algorithm relies on the Collection object throwing an error if you try to add multiple items with the same key.

First we find the duplicate items (`CountIf >`), and then we add them to a Collection.  Knowing that the error will be from the duplicate item, we skip over the additions that produce the error, and are left with only single entries of the duplicate items.

In more complex situations, one can test to see which error is returned, or use a Dictionary object.

```
Option Explicit
Function ConcatDups(rg As Range) As String
    Dim C As Range
    Dim col As Collection
    Dim V As Variant
    Dim sTemp As String
Set col = New Collection

On Error Resume Next 'collect single instance of Dups
With WorksheetFunction
For Each C In rg
    If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(rg, C) > 1 Then _
    col.Add C.Text, C.Text
Next C
End With
On Error GoTo 0

For Each V In col
    sTemp = sTemp & V
Next V

ConcatDups = sTemp

End Function
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot, Ron. That was really quick!

Comment: @Max I will add an explanation of how it works in a minute.